# Type checking for SimpleChanges interface in ngOnChanges hook

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, lifecycle, typescript2.1, ngonchanges

It would be great if we had type checking inside the SimpleChanges typescript parameter of ngOnChanges hook for the current Component.

This would prevent us from errors in the properties we check.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using *TypeScript 2.1* and the *keyof* functionality I have figured out the following type declarations (based on SimpleChanges) which seems to give us the necessary typed access to Component's properties:

```
export type ComponentChange<T, P extends keyof T> = {
    previousValue: T[P];
    currentValue: T[P];
    firstChange: boolean;
};

export type ComponentChanges<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: ComponentChange<T, P>;
};
```

Using those, declarations vscode editor automatically fetches the type info and auto completes the changes properties:

[image]

One problem though is that the *changes* parameter now will list each and every property of the component (and not only the @Input() properties) but I haven't figure out a better way than this.

Comment: Use inheritance, even if you could iterate all inputs, not all inputs maybe necessarily changing. Extending the Simple Changes interface will make explicit the inputs the component is expecting to change. Anyway just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the following solution, adapted from https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17560#issuecomment-624161007

```js
export type SimpleChangeTyped<T> = Omit<SimpleChange, SimpleChange['previousValue'] | SimpleChange['currentValue']>
  & {
    previousValue: T;
    currentValue: T;
  };

export type SimpleChangesTyped<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: SimpleChangeTyped<T[K]>;
};
```

This solution has the following advantages:

- Fully typed / Works with intellisense
- Does not overwrite/union's properties that inherently present on SimpleChange
- Works with `this`
- Protects against bad properties
- Will throw an error if the angular devs ever decide to change the `previousValue` or `currentValue` properties on SimpleChange

UsageExample:

```js
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChangesTyped<YourComponent>): void { // Or use SimpleChangesTyped<this>
    changes.someComponentProperty; // GOOD: Will identify the changes object with correct types
    changes.someOtherProperty; // BAD: Property 'someOtherProperty' does not exist on type 'SimpleChangesTyped<YourComponent>'.ts(2339)
    changes.someComponentProperty.currentValue; // GOOD: Will identify the type of the someComponentProperty property
    changes.someComponentProperty.firstChange; // GOOD: Will identify the type of the SimpleChange firstChange property (boolean)
    changes.someComponentProperty.someOtherProperty; // BAD: Property 'someOtherProperty' does not exist on type 'SimpleChangeTyped<SomeComponentPropertyType>'.ts(2339)
  }
```

The only downside of this method is that it does not inherit/union of SimpleChanges and thus if any properties are added to this interface in the future they will not be valid for SimpleChangesTyped. I tried using the following variant:

```js
export type SimpleChangesTyped<T> =
  Omit<SimpleChanges, keyof T> &
  {
    [K in keyof T]: SimpleChangeTyped<T[K]>;
  };
```

However sadly this does not work, since you end up allowing all key's again.

Answer (score 2):

There is [a solution](https://netbasal.com/create-a-typed-version-of-simplechanges-in-angular-451f86593003) from Netanel Basal

```js
type MarkFunctionPropertyNames<T> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends Function | Subject<any> ? never : Key;
}
type ExcludeFunctionPropertyNames<T extends object> = MarkFunctionPropertyNames<T>[keyof T];
type ExcludeFunctions<T extends object> = Pick<T, ExcludeFunctionPropertyNames<T>>;
export type NgChanges<TComponent extends object, TProps = ExcludeFunctions<TComponent>> = {
  [Key in keyof TProps]: {
    previousValue: TProps[Key];
    currentValue: TProps[Key];
    firstChange: boolean;
    isFirstChange(): boolean;
  }
}
// ...
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
  ngOnChanges(changes: NgChanges<MyComponent>) { }
}
```

Comment: Notice that with this unit tests might [need to be modified](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17560#issuecomment-895859473) to `const changes: NgChanges<MyComponent> = {} as any;
      changes.something = new SimpleChange(null, someData, true);
      component.ngOnChanges(changes);`.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the issue using inheritance. First I create typed interface which extends SimpleChange class. You only need to do this once and import it in your components which need it.

```
interface TypedChange<T> extends SimpleChange
{
    previousValue: T;
    currentValue: T;
}
```

Second we extend the SimpleChanges interface with ones expected to change in our component. For example

```
interface MyComponentChanges extends SimpleChanges
{
    RefreshQueue: TypedChange<number>
}
```

Lastly the implementation is

```
public ngOnChanges(changes: MyComponentChanges): void
{
    if (changes.RefreshQueue)
    {
        if (!changes.RefreshQueue.isFirstChange())
        {
            if (changes.RefreshQueue.currentValue == 1)
            {
                DoSomething();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Intellisense screen shot below

[image]